# Symfony2 and Doctrine: just a single record deleted from a multiple request

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

The action included at the end of this post is called from an ajax call via jQuery. When I try to delete more than one record, just the first is deleted but the flash messages are printed for every request.

I checked the input data and it is correct. No exception are throwed.

Any idea? Thanks!

```
/**
 * @Route("/cancella", name="training_plan_activity_edition_final_delete")
 * @Method({"POST"})
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function deleteAction(Request $request)
{
    if (!$request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        throw new \Exception('this controller allows only ajax requests');
    }
    $ids = json_decode($request->get('ids'), true);
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    foreach ($ids as $id) {
        if($id <> 'on') {
            $trainingPlanActionEditionFinal = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository('TrainingPlanBundle:TrainingPlanActionEditionFinal')
                ->find($id);
            if (!$trainingPlanActionEditionFinal) {
                throw $this->createNotFoundException(
                    'Training plan action edition final with id ' . $id . ' not found'
                );
            }
            $trainingPlanSlug = $trainingPlanActionEditionFinal->getSlug();
            try {
                $em->remove($trainingPlanActionEditionFinal);
                $em->flush();
                $this->get('session')->getFlashbag()->add('success', 'Cancellazione dell\'edizione avvenuta con successo');
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->get('session')->getFlashbag()->add('error', 'Impossibile cancellare l\'edizione');
            }
        }
    }
    return new Response($this->generateUrl('training_plan_action_edition_final_list', array(
            'trainingPlanSlug' => $trainingPlanSlug
        )
    ));
}
```

Comment: I suggest you var_dump ($ids) after json_decode and also var_dump the id of the loaded object from your repository->find - that should show any issues.

Comment: Starting from **Symfony2.6** you could also use the more convenient [method `dump()`](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-vardumper-component), from the controller or from Teig. It will use the profiler toolbar.

Comment: Thx! I have found the problem. When I put the code $trainingPlanSlug = $trainingPlanActionEditionFinal->getSlug(); outside the foreach loop everything works... But I don't understand why!